# SQL - Update query only update one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run an update query on my Stock table based on a certain barcode field.

Schema of Stock Table.

[image]

The query I am trying to run is

```
Update tblStock set Quantity = Quantity + 10, Total = Quantity * PPrice where barcode = 'shandar'
```

when Executing this query the Quantity Field gets updated but Total Field remains unchanged, I want to Multiply Quantity with PPrice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Total = Quantity * PPrice` refers to the existing value of `Quanity` as it is before the update. You need to do `Total = (Quantity  + 10) * PPrice`

Comment: Quantity = Quantity + 10 is only once after that I want to multiply the updated Quantity value to the PPrice Value and set it in Total based on the barcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to define the new quantity in the `FROM` clause, and then use that value:

```
Update s
    set Quantity = v.Quantity,
        Total = v.Quantity * s.PPrice
    from tblStock s cross apply
         (values (s.Quantity + 10)) v(quantity)
    where s.barcode = 'shandar';
```

Repeating a simple operation such as `quantity + 10` isn't a big deal.  However, if the calculation is more complex, it is simpler to do it once.

That said, you might be better off with `total` as a *computed* column.  Then it is just correct -- and never has to be updated.  Drop it from the table and then re-add it as:

```
alter table tblStock add total as ( quantity * pprice );
```

Then the value of `total` is always correct, because it is calculated when you query the table.

Comment: Quantity = Quantity + 10 is only once after that I want to multiply the updated Quantity value to the PPrice Value and set it in Total based on the barcode. –

Comment: @SMHasnain . . . I'm missing your point.  In this answer, `quantity + 10` only appears once.  That is the point of this answer.

Comment: the update is for only one-row Quantity field is updated with quantity +10 then after that, it moves further to another field and updates the Total Field value with the new updated value of Quantity * PPrice.

Comment: @SMHasnain . . . That is what the code in this answer does.  I repeat:  `quantity + 10` only appears once in the answer, not twice.

Comment: when I use that snippet it gives me a multipart error, but the new information you have about the computed field is really helpful, I need to read about the cross apply

Comment: @SMHasnain . . . Here is a db<>fiddle just to illustrate that the code compiles:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e830c8ba9e31b7e36f12f67b93fffffe.

Comment: you are correct the code compiles on fiddle, I think it's a version issue as I am using SQLServer 2012, but its getting really interesting because you taught me a new thing.

Comment: I have also run it on different fiddle  it gives me the same error https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8DVeXFdsrEBwHg168GZU2o/39

Comment: @SMHasnain . . . This code is SQL Server code -- just as the question is tagged.  If you have a question about MySQL, ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 4):

For your case, Once the first column "Quantity" is updated the update statement is not completed ,yet it has to update the Second Column "Total". So it takes the actual records from the table not the updated one. Else you can Split this into 2 updates for Different Columns.

Then You need to do like this:

Because, while updating the table the SQL Server considers the previous data until the code executes successfully without any Error.

This Frequently Updated/Deleted/Inserted rows/records can be viewed by using inserted & deleted tables by using Triggers

```
Update tblStock set Quantity = Quantity + 10, Total = (Quantity + 10)* PPrice 
where barcode = 'shandar'
```

Comment: Quantity = Quantity + 10 is only once after that I want to multiply the updated Quantity value to the PPrice Value and set it in Total based on the barcode. –

Comment: For your case Once the first column "Quantity" is updated the update statement is not completed ,yet it has to update the Second Column "Total". So it takes the actual records from the table not the updated one.  Else you can Split this into 2 updates for Different Columns. -- @SMHasnain

Comment: yeh thats what I did just now It's really strange that SQL does not support this kind of query, please update your answer so I Upvote all that helped.